# How to go back to previous screen in React Native with goBack() function?

Tags: react-native

Just started to learn React Native and trying to understanding form the very beginning.

#### **My goals:**

1. I need help to understanding the `.goBack()` function that i used in
   `<Stack.Screen>`.
2. Understanding why the `.goBack()` function work in `MemberLogin.js` but not in the header at `App.js`?

#### **My thoughts:**

1. I realize that the button that I created is inside the page itself unlinke the `<HeaderButtons>` in the `App.js`. That's why my `<Button>` in `MemberLogin.js` works because it can be detectable and grab the value from the first page?

#### **My expectation(Need Help!):**

1. Back button on my header should be able to go back to the previous screen.

#### **My try-out:**

1. Create a `<Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>` components in `MemberLogin.js` and test if is work? Yes it work!
2. Add `onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}` function in my `App.js`, return an error `Can't find variable:navigate`
3. Changed `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}` function in my `App.js` not working either.

#### **My reference**

1. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#going-back

#### **My codes**

In `App.js`

```
export default function App({navigation}) {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>

        // Home
        <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('This is menu.')}>
                <Image style={styles.headerIcons} source={menuIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </HeaderButtons>
            ),
            headerRight: () => (
            )
        }}
        />

        //MemberLogin
        <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Home')}>
                <Image style={styles.headerIcons} source={backIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </HeaderButtons>
            ),
            headerRight: () => (
            )
        }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
}
```

In `MemberLogin.js`

```
export default function App({navigation}) {


    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add goback button in your header you can use navigation option inside stack.screen tag.

In your App.js file add

```
<Stack.Screen
name="Home"
component={Home}
options={{
   headerShown: true,
   navigationOptions: {
      header: ({ goBack }) => ({
      left: <Left onPress={goBack} />,
      }),
 },
}}
/>
```